# Create a popwindow on click of dropdown(There is no selection in the dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a popwindow on click or onfocus of the dropdown . In the popwindow I should display the checkboxes with multiselect option.I searched for this kind but I couldn't find any references.
Can anyone write code for this using jQuery.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #pop
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        display: none;
    }
    #container
    {
        position: relative;
        width:500px;
        margin:100px auto;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #ddown
    {
        width:100px;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="ddown" >
    <option></option>
</select>
<div id="pop" >
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Some Check box here</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ddown").on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#pop").show();
    })
    $("#pop").click(function(){
        $("#pop").hide();
    })
</script>
</html>
```